# regex in a $split() (jsonata) function giving "Regular expression matches zero length string" why?

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, split, jsonata

I'm  having a string text like below, i wanna split the text whenever there's a **new line AND starts with a date dd/mm/yyyy.**

I'm using jsonata $split() function in javascript. However, i get a jsonata error as the following "Regular expression matches zero length string". Please help how can i solve this.

```
text = "22/03/2012 intro 20/10/2019\n" + 
       "22/03/2012 body\n" + 
       "more body 22/04/2020\n" +
      "22/03/2012 stuff more stuff"


$split(text , /\\r?\\n(?=(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \\/.](?:0[1-9]|1[012])[- \\/.](?:19|20)\\d\\d)/))
//I want the output to be [ "22/03/2012 intro 20/10/2019",
//                           "22/03/2012 body more body 22/04/2020",
//                           "22/03/2012 stuff more stuff] 
// But my output now is [ "22/03/2012 intro 20/10/2019",
//                           "22/03/2012 body/n + more body 22/04/2020",
//                           "22/03/2012 stuff more stuff]
```

Comment: Have you tried to split on `\n` instead of `^`, because `^` also matches at the beginning of the string. [See if this demo helps](https://regex101.com/r/DfsJon/3). I'd further escape the `/` inside the pattern.

Comment: hey @bobblebubble, thanks for helping out but turns out that my input is a big string that includes "\n" & "+" so that wont work ://

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
const str = "22/03/2012 intro\n" +
"22/03/2012 body\n" +
"more body\n" +
"22/03/2012 stuff\n" +
"more stuff\n";

console.log(str.match(/^[0-9][0-9][- /.][0-9][0-9][- /.][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-zA-Z\s]+(?:[a-zA-Z\s]+)/gm));
// Will log ["22/03/2012 intro\n","22/03/2012 body\nmore body\n", "22/03/2012 stuff\nmore stuff\n"]
```

Comment: hey thanks for your help, but unfortunately it turns out that  my input is a big string that includes "\n" & "+" so that wont work ://. I tried running it on the input right now but it only returns the first element

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
$split($replace(text, /(\r?\n)\s*\+\s*(?=\d{2}[- \/.]\d{2}[- \/.]\d{4})|\r?\n\s*\+\s*/g, '$1'), /\r?\n/)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/RbGk8a/1).

The first `$replace` removes plus symbols and newlines and replaces with a line ending where necessary.

The `$split` one splits with carriage return  + line feed or just line feed.

Comment: Hey thank you so much for you help and detailed answer! However, my input has changed it's a long string that includes "\n" & "+" so unfortunately wont work ://